# OPL CPLEX Deterministic Time Limit (Ticks)

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

Based on https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.8.0.0?topic=parameters-deterministic-time-limit

Deterministic time limit is not available for OPL. However, my process is always killed if I reach around 1.770.000ish ticks. I would like to set the maximum ticks (like time limit) and return whatever solution that they have.

I know we can set the limit in seconds, but I might change platform to run this.
Is there any other way or tricks to set deterministic time limit for OPL language?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OPL documentation you can read

[image]

where you can see that the Identifier is 1127

In [How to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/) [How to set a setting that is not available](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/setunavailablesetting.mod) will do what you need.

```
execute {
// 1127 is dettimelimit
    cplex.params[1127] = 10.0;
}
```